# How to properly renderDataTable in Shiny when theres is whitespace in the column headers

Tags: r, datatables, shiny

I am rendering a `datatable` from a `data.frame` to which I've given names like "Agent Name" for readability's sake. When I deply a shiny app to view this data as a DataTable, the whitespace in the column names has been replaced by ".". How do I avoid this behavior and keep the whitespace? Thanks.

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example that demonstrates the issue you are having.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are encountering R's `make.names` function. By default data.frames names are checked with the `make.names` function. You can prevent this check by using the `check.names` when creating your data.frame:

```
library(shiny)
runApp(
  list(
    ui = fluidPage(dataTableOutput("mytable"))
    , server = function(input, output, session){
      output$mytable <- renderDataTable({
        data.frame("my 1st col" = 1:3, "my 2nd col" = 4:6, check.names = FALSE)   
      })      
    }
  )
)
```

[image]